# MySQL: need assistance with MySQL logic

Tags: mysql

I am trying to work through a MySQL problem and I almost have it... 
The Question is...

*What query would you run to get all the cities in Mexico with a population of greater than 500,000? Arrange the result by population in descending order.*

***Here is the table I am working off of...***

[image]

***My current code...***

```
SELECT cities.name, cities.population
FROM countries
LEFT JOIN cities
ON countries.id = cities.country_id
WHERE cities.population < 500000
```

I feel like I should be super close. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. All I needed was a little more detail!

Old code...

```
SELECT cities.name, cities.population
FROM countries
LEFT JOIN cities
ON countries.id = cities.country_id
WHERE cities.population < 500000
```

New code...

```
SELECT cities.name, cities.population
FROM countries 
LEFT JOIN cities
ON countries.id = cities.country_id
WHERE countries.name = 'Mexico' AND cities.population < 500000
GROUP BY cities.name
ORDER BY cities.name DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

And where is the problem? Looks simple ...without testing ;)

select t1.name, t1.population
from countries t0 join cities t1 on
    t0.id = t1.country_id
and t1.population > 500000
order by t1.population desc